# How do I use the object as a parameter in my function and how do I recall the function

Tags: javascript, function, object, parameters

My code works separately ( the object prints, the math formula calculates properly), however I do not understand how to connect the object in the formula and get it to print my final answer.

The only think I knew to try was different parameter names but I do not know how parameters work.

```
// Assignment 2
// Write a function that accepts one parameter to calculate ...
// ... the surface area of the outside of a box


// Introducing the object & asking the user for the three measuremeants

let sides = {
    a: prompt ("Enter the measuremeants of side A"),
    b: prompt ("Enter the measuremeants of side B"),
    c: prompt ("Enter the measuremeants of side C")
    };

// console.log(sides.a + sides.b + sides.c);  - testing object

// Introducing the function

function calcArea(sides) {

// let a=1 let b=3 let c=4 - testing math formula
let surfaceArea = 2*a*b + 2*b*c + 2*a*c;
console.log("Side A=" + a + ", Side B=" + b + ", Side C=" + c);
console.log("The area is: " + surfaceArea);
};

//Recalling the function
calcArea(surfaceArea);
```

These are the expectations of what my program is supposed to do :

- Create an object variable that will store the length of all 3 sides of the box.
- Prompt the user for 3 side lengths and store them in the object using properties a , b , and c .
- Create a function named calcArea that accepts one parameter, the object we created earlier. Using the
  formula below, calculate and return the surface area. (2ab+2bc+2ac)
- Use template strings to display the three sides of the box and the final surface area with descriptive text.

For example:

> ```
> Side A=3, Side B=4, Side C=5
> The area is: 94
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the function is using the standalone variables `a`, `b`, and `c`, you can pass the object into the function and destructure the `a`, `b`, and `c` properties immediately, allowing you to reference them as standalone variables and use them in your formula:

```js
const sides = {
  a: prompt("Enter the measuremeants of side A"),
  b: prompt("Enter the measuremeants of side B"),
  c: prompt("Enter the measuremeants of side C")
};
function calcArea({ a, b, c }) {
  const surfaceArea = 2 * a * b + 2 * b * c + 2 * a * c;
  console.log("Side A=" + a + ", Side B=" + b + ", Side C=" + c);
  console.log("The area is: " + surfaceArea);
};
calcArea(sides);
```

Without destructuring or extracting into individual variables, you would have to change each reference to `a`, `b`, and `c` inside the function to `sides.a`, `sides.b`, and `sides.c`:

```js
const sides = {
  a: prompt("Enter the measuremeants of side A"),
  b: prompt("Enter the measuremeants of side B"),
  c: prompt("Enter the measuremeants of side C")
};

function calcArea(sides) {
  const surfaceArea = 2 * sides.a * sides.b + 2 * sides.b * sides.c + 2 * sides.a * sides.c;
  console.log("Side A=" + sides.a + ", Side B=" + sides.b + ", Side C=" + sides.c);
  console.log("The area is: " + surfaceArea);
};
calcArea(sides);
```

To use template literals as well, use backticks instead of `"` delimiters and concatenation:

```js
const sides = {
  a: prompt("Enter the measuremeants of side A"),
  b: prompt("Enter the measuremeants of side B"),
  c: prompt("Enter the measuremeants of side C")
};
function calcArea({ a, b, c }) {
  const surfaceArea = 2 * a * b + 2 * b * c + 2 * a * c;
  console.log(`Side A=${a}, Side B=${b}, Side C=${c}`);
  console.log(`The area is: ${surfaceArea}`);
};
calcArea(sides);
```

You might also note that it's generally preferable to use `const` rather than `let` - `let` is for when you need to *reassign* a variable later.

Comment: The second example was the most helpful and at the same level of where we are currently learning so I understood it the best.
Thank you very much for all your help. I understand why I could not just leave a, b, c as stand alone in the formulas.

Answer (score 0):

`a`, `b`, and `c` are properties/keys of `sides`, you have to access them via that object. Also, your `calcArea` function is set up to take a `sides` parameter, but you've currently got it being called with the `surfaceArea` function variable which is not in scope at that point.

```js
let sides = {
    a: prompt ("Enter the measuremeants of side A"),
    b: prompt ("Enter the measuremeants of side B"),
    c: prompt ("Enter the measuremeants of side C")
    };

function calcArea(sides) {
  // To access object properties, use "dot notation" (object.property).
  // You can't simply try to access the property directly.
  let surfaceArea = 2 * sides.a * sides.b + 2 * sides.b* sides.c + 2 * sides.a * sides.c;
  console.log("Side A=" + sides.a + ", Side B=" + sides.b + ", Side C=" + sides.c);
  console.log("The area is: " + surfaceArea);
};

calcArea(sides);  // You have to pass your sides object into the function.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking a minute and helping me out with my assignment !